Flutter Test > (ubuntu) Docker container > Mount volumes: (existing code) and (.pub_cache)
My goldens fail on GithubActions, flutter test run on Ubuntu image, since MacOS renders UI a bit differently. We're talking 0% < diff < 2%.
So I decided to generate the goldens on Ubuntu image, on my local machine, so that the tests pass.
Docker to the rescue! I've attached my Dockerfile and a Makefile.
tl;dr

Dockerfile downloads the flutter SDK and sets up env.

Makefile runs the docker container and then runs the test inside it


Fun part:
I'm trying to mount my existing code dir, .pub_cache dir into the Docker container to avoid pulling the code and running flutter pub get
But my tests are failing!
Note: This test passes when I run it on my local machine
make test_app test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart

wildr_flutter git:(-ubantu-golden-gen-f...shold) ✗ make test_app test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart
(cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wildr_flutter && docker build --build-arg flutter_version=$(flutter --version | grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*') -t docker_tests $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wildr_flutter/docker/ && docker run -ti -v $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wildr_flutter:/home/developer/wildr_flutter  -v ~/.pub-cache:/home/developer/.pub-cache -e PUB_CACHE="/home/developer/.pub-cache" docker_tests /bin/sh -c "cd wildr_flutter && pwd && flutter test "test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart" "" """)
[+] Building 0.5s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                         docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 601B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                                                                            0.4s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:a6d2b38300ce017add71440577d5b0a90460d0e57fd7aec21dd0d1b0761bbfb2                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-11-jdk wget                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] WORKDIR /home/developer                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b 3.19.4                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [6/6] RUN flutter doctor                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f419879c20150c33b6f46131477b21aacf4122f6760ee6eac8b9e2aba75fdc40                                                               0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker_tests                                                                                                            0.0s

Whats Next?
  1. Sign in to your Docker account → docker login
  2. View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
/home/developer/wildr_flutter
00:27 +0 -1: loading /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart [E]                                                                 
  Error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
  package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart 10:3  throwToolExit
  package:flutter_tools/src/compile.dart 885:13    DefaultResidentCompiler._compile.<fn>
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 87:11        _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 21:11        _EventSinkWrapper.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 241:11       _StringAdapterSink.close
  dart:convert/line_splitter.dart 141:11           _LineSplitterSink.close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 132:24       _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 87:11        _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 21:11        _EventSinkWrapper.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 241:11       _StringAdapterSink.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 295:20       _Utf8ConversionSink.close
  dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart 78:18       _ConverterStreamEventSink.close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 132:24       _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 792:19         _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 647:7          _StreamController._closeUnchecked
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 640:5          _StreamController.close
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 2454:21          _Socket._onData
  dart:async/zone.dart 1415:13                     _rootRunUnary
  dart:async/zone.dart 1308:19                     _CustomZone.runUnary
  dart:async/zone.dart 1217:7                      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 339:11               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 271:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._add
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 784:19         _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 658:7          _StreamController._add
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 606:5          _StreamController.add
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 1943:35          new _RawSocket.<fn>
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 1372:18          _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue
  dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:21         _microtaskLoop
  dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5          _startMicrotaskLoop
  dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 118:13     _runPendingImmediateCallback
  dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 185:5      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage
  
  Failed to load "/home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart": Compilation failed for testPath=/home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart

To run this test again: /home/developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart test /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart -p vm --plain-name 'loading /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart'
00:28 +0 -1: Some tests failed.                                                                                                                                
make: *** [test_app] Error 1

Output when I enter the container, make run_bash

run flutter pub get
run flutter test test/common/cached_image_view_test.dart

Also, after running flutter pub get from the container, the External Libs (what AndroidStudio shows) change and show no Dart Packages
flutter pub get



Before
AFter









developer@be8993ac66b3:~/wildr_flutter$ flutter test test/community/join_community_page_test.dart 
00:37 +0 -1: loading /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/community/join_community_page_test.dart [E]                                                            
  Error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
  package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart 10:3  throwToolExit
  package:flutter_tools/src/compile.dart 885:13    DefaultResidentCompiler._compile.<fn>
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 87:11        _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 21:11        _EventSinkWrapper.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 241:11       _StringAdapterSink.close
  dart:convert/line_splitter.dart 141:11           _LineSplitterSink.close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 132:24       _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 87:11        _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 21:11        _EventSinkWrapper.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 241:11       _StringAdapterSink.close
  dart:convert/string_conversion.dart 295:20       _Utf8ConversionSink.close
  dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart 78:18       _ConverterStreamEventSink.close
  dart:async/stream_transformers.dart 132:24       _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone
  dart:async/zone.dart 1391:47                     _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1301:19                     _CustomZone.run
  dart:async/zone.dart 1209:7                      _CustomZone.runGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 392:13               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 402:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 291:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._close
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 792:19         _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendDone
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 647:7          _StreamController._closeUnchecked
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 640:5          _StreamController.close
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 2454:21          _Socket._onData
  dart:async/zone.dart 1415:13                     _rootRunUnary
  dart:async/zone.dart 1308:19                     _CustomZone.runUnary
  dart:async/zone.dart 1217:7                      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 339:11               _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
  dart:async/stream_impl.dart 271:7                _BufferingStreamSubscription._add
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 784:19         _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 658:7          _StreamController._add
  dart:async/stream_controller.dart 606:5          _StreamController.add
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 1943:35          new _RawSocket.<fn>
  dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart 1372:18          _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue
  dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:21         _microtaskLoop
  dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5          _startMicrotaskLoop
  dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 118:13     _runPendingImmediateCallback
  dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 185:5      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage
  
  Failed to load "/home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/community/join_community_page_test.dart": Compilation failed for testPath=/home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/community/join_community_page_test.dart

To run this test again: /home/developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart test /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/community/join_community_page_test.dart -p vm --plain-name 'loading /home/developer/wildr_flutter/test/community/join_community_page_test.dart'


Dockerfile
# github actions ubuntu-latest is 22.04
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Prerequisites
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-11-jdk wget
# Set up new user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash developer
USER developer
WORKDIR /home/developer

# flutter_version=$(flutter --version | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')
ARG flutter_version

RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b ${flutter_version}

ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/flutter/bin"


# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor

Here's my Makefile
# set the path of the flutter installation on the local machine to share it with the docker container
flutter_dir = $$(which flutter)

# set the path of the current project directory on the local machine to share it with the docker container
wildr_flutter_dir = $$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wildr_flutter

# set the flutter version to use the same in the docker container
flutter_version = $$(flutter --version | grep -m 1 -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*')

# Base command to run the docker container
docker_build_image := docker build --build-arg flutter_version=$(flutter_version) -t docker_tests $(wildr_flutter_dir)/docker/
docker_run_image_docker_tests = docker run -it -v $(wildr_flutter_dir):/home/developer/wildr_flutter  -v ~/.pub-cache:/home/developer/.pub-cache -e PUB_CACHE="/home/developer/.pub-cache" docker_tests

# get every argument after the make command
RUN_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

# check if the update-goldens option is given
ifeq ($(findstring update-goldens,$(RUN_ARGS)),update-goldens)
 update-goldens="--update-goldens"
else
 update-goldens=""
endif

# check if the coverage option is given
ifeq ($(findstring coverage,$(RUN_ARGS)),coverage)
 coverage="--coverage"
else
 coverage=""
endif

# We check if a testPath option is given
ifeq ($(filter test/%.dart,$(RUN_ARGS)),)
 testPath=""
else
 testPath="$(filter test/%.dart,$(RUN_ARGS))"
endif

test_app: CMD = cd wildr_flutter && \
                pwd && \
                flutter test $(testPath) $(update-goldens) $(coverage)

test_app: 
    (cd $(wildr_flutter_dir) && $(docker_build_image) && $(docker_run_image_docker_tests) /bin/sh -c "$(CMD)")

run_bash: 
    (cd $(wildr_flutter_dir) && $(docker_build_image) && $(docker_run_image_docker_tests) bash)

I tried manually running flutter pub get in the container. No luck :/
